# to get last modified user of SharePoint Online default.aspx pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, pnp-powershell, pnp, default

I want to get the user name who has last modified default.aspx pages in SharePoint Online site. **Only option is to use PnP powershell** for **SharePoint Online** sites.

e.g https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/home/**default.aspx**

Please assist.

Comment: page properties are not updating even if i am editing the page(without check out). Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to get the modified by porperty:

```
$web=Get-PnPFile -Url /sites/path/default.aspx
$web.ModifiedBy
```

It will shows the user login name and Email address